# dbms_xmldom - How to get the <?xml tag

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to get the line `<?xml ....?>` at the start of the XML document using the PL/SQL Package `dbms_xmldom`. Here is the code so far

```
declare
  l_dom   dbms_xmldom.DOMDocument;
  l_clob  clob;
  l_node  dbms_xmldom.DOMNode;

begin
  l_dom := dbms_xmldom.newDomDocument;
  l_node := dbms_xmldom.makeNode(l_dom);

  l_node := dbms_xmldom.appendChild(l_node, 
              dbms_xmldom.makeNode(
                dbms_xmldom.createElement(l_dom, 'root')
              )
            );

  dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_clob, true);

  dbms_xmldom.writeToClob(l_dom, l_clob);
  dbms_output.put_line(l_clob);
end;
```

The output is:

```
<root/>
```

Expect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root/>
```

Any pointers on how to do this would get great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the record - here is what you need to add

```
dbms_xmldom.setVersion(l_dom, '1.0" encoding="UTF-8');
```

after creating the document

Comment: It took a bit of digging to find this out

Answer (score 0):

The  prolog is usually added automatically by XML serialization, so you shouldn't need to add it yourself, but if you want to you can with XMLRoot.

Your method for generating XML is quite inefficient.  You should be looking at XMLElement, XMLForest, XMLAgg etc.

Here's a simple root and child example, with prolog in one line of code.

```
select XMLRoot(XMLElement("root", XMLElement("child", 12)), version '1.0') from dual

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <child>12</child>
</root>
```

Comment: I have just put a snippet - as the rest of the code is using PL/SQL to generate the rest of XML document

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.